# How to use CDF in standalone mode

Tags: pentaho

I'm using pentaho CDE which is excellent. I've seen you can use a dashboard in standalone with an obscure url like

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/pentaho-cdf/RenderXCDF?solution=bi-developers&path=/analysis&action=Test.wcdf&template=mantle
```

However I can't get it work neither find a document about it. Does anybody know what the parameters stand for or a link to an official documentation ?

For example I'm not sure what is the difference between the solution and the path. Also should I use a wcdf or an cdfde ? (what is the difference between them).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you posted is for CDF dashboards, not CDE. They are not the same, although CDE is based and built on CDF.

That url should work for CDF dashboards. The url for CDE dashboards is

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/pentaho-cdf-dd/Render?solution=foo&path=&file=bar.wcdf
```

file is always the wcdf
solution is the top folder on the repository browser
path is the intermediate folder path from the first folder down to the wcdf file. So if your wcdf is at foo/bar/my.wcdf, solution=foo, path=/bar and file=my.wcdf

Comment: I'm not sure I understand between cdf dashboard and cde one but it works. Many thanks