# How to see CDE dashboard for external user in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

Hi I am a  newbie in Pentaho I used Pentaho community version Using Pentaho CDE dashboard I created my own dashboard. My question is How do I get the dashboard URL to use in viewing the my developed dashboard outside of the biserver? for a external customer?

Answer (score 4):

double click on the dashboard tab in PUC.
This will open a new window with a direct url to the dashboard.

EDIT: If you want to be able to open a dashboard on an iframe without giving away authentication details, you can:

- Create an user that can only access that dashboard. That way the credentials on the URL will be harmless
- Define the dashboard accessible by the anonymous user.
- Change the authentication method for your Pentaho server. There's a lot of information regarding that on Pentaho infocenter.

Comment: Hi I tried this it work fine but when I embedded this url on jsp page using iframe it not display my pentaho url

Comment: Hi, I solved that issues displaying iframe I move pentaho-bi server on my existing running tomcat and it work fine, but my problem is that I want to display iframe link without user name and password so if any user view my web page they not able to find out my pentaho-bi server user name and password, how should I manged this?

Comment: @PedroVale I'm adding post variables (user_id and pssword) but apache/tomcat authentication user/password message is shown. I'm running bi-server by './start-pentaho.sh' script and default configuration. Must I chan ge any apache/tomcat parameter to avoid the authentication? Thank you

Comment: yeah, post variables won't work there. You'll need to configure and implement SSO to implement it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782432/1813570) and [this blog](http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/embedded-analytics-in-pentaho-with.html) useful.

The problem you have here is the access to the URL, which is simple:

1. right-click the CDE file (blue icon)
2. click "Open In New Window"
3. the URL in the new browser window is the URL you're looking for

[image: screenshot]

When adding to iframe, you may also find it convenient appending login-details (user_id=your_user_name, password=your_password) to the URL. Otherwise it requires you to log-in, which is painful to business users.

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/pentaho-cdf-dd/Render?solution=foo&path=&file=bar.wcdf&userid=your_user_name&password=your_password
```

Comment: same thing, in browse files, single click on one of the CDE file, and then "Open in a new window".